# How can I color patch edges like patch faces (using the colormap)?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, colormap

I've got several patches in a figure (see minimal working example below). Currently, these patches have a face color that is determined by `FaceVertexCData`, a scalar that references the current colorbar, and an edge color that is determined by `EdgeColor`, a RGB vector. What I want to do is remove the face color and have the edges be the same color as the original face color of their respective patch.

Removing the face color is simple with the `FaceAlpha` property, but I can't seem to figure out how to turn the  `FaceVertexCData` property into its equivalent RGB code so that I can assign it to `EdgeColor`.

```
h.fig = figure;
h.patch(1) = patch([0 1 1 0],[0 0 .3 .3],10);
h.patch(2) = patch([0 1 1 0],[.5 .5 .9 .9],5);
set(h.patch, 'FaceAlpha', 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple way to color your edges. If you make your [color data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#property_d0e725825) the same size as your vertex data (i.e. the `X` and `Y` arguments), you can set the [`'EdgeColor'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#property_d0e724646) to `'flat'` so that it uses the interpolated color values from your colormap:

```
h.fig = figure;
h.patch(1) = patch([0 1 1 0], [0 0 .3 .3], 10.*ones(1, 4));
h.patch(2) = patch([0 1 1 0], [.5 .5 .9 .9], 5.*ones(1, 4));
set(h.patch, 'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', 'flat');
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First get the current colormap and the colorbar

```
currentCmap = colormap; % get the current colormap
theColorbar = colorbar; % get the current colorbar
```

then find the cdata values in the colorbar (there might be a better way of doing this).

```
colorVertexList = linspace(theColorbar.Limits(1), theColorbar.Limits(2), size(currentCmap, 1));
```

To find the indices of the patch colors in the above list, I just use the smallest difference, as shown below

```
[~, patch1ColorIndex] = min(abs(h.patch(1).FaceVertexCData-colorVertexList));
[~, patch2ColorIndex] = min(abs(h.patch(2).FaceVertexCData-colorVertexList));
```

then you can get the rgb values from the colormap

```
patch1Color = currentCmap(patch1ColorIndex, :);
patch2Color = currentCmap(patch2ColorIndex, :);
```

and set the colors

```
set(h.patch, 'FaceAlpha', 0);
set(h.patch(1), 'EdgeColor', patch1Color);
set(h.patch(2), 'EdgeColor', patch2Color);
```

Answer (score 1):

For future users, I've implemented Vahe Tshitoyan's solution as a function.

```
function RGB = cdata2rgb(ax,val)
% CDATA2RGB convert cdata values to their corresponding RGB vector.
%   RGB = cdata2rgb(ax,val) converts the values in n-by-1 vector val to
%   an n-by-3 RGB matrix. Uses the colormap and colorbar associated with
%   axis handle ax. 
h.cmap = colormap(ax);

CDataList = linspace(ax.CLim(1), ax.CLim(2), size(h.cmap, 1));

[~, idx] = min(abs(val-CDataList),[],2); %Change to bsxfun if implicit expansion is not supported. 
RGB = h.cmap(idx,:);

end
```

Which makes my final code:

```
h.fig = figure;
h.ax = axes();
h.patch(1) = patch([0 1 1 0],[0 0 .3 .3],10);
h.patch(2) = patch([0 1 1 0],[.5 .5 .9 .9],5);
set(h.patch, 'FaceAlpha', 0);
set(h.patch(1), 'EdgeColor', cdata2rgb(h.ax,h.patch(1).FaceVertexCData));
set(h.patch(2), 'EdgeColor', cdata2rgb(h.ax,h.patch(2).FaceVertexCData));
```